# Is there a spellchecker for jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I know there is a spell checker built into textviews ([XML](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework)), but I can't seem to find an equivalent in Jetpack Compose. Is there a way to use the old one, was I just unable to find it, or is this a feature that needs to be added?

I found this [ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230113955) so I believe there is currently no way to do so, so is there a way to get this done with what we currently have available in android? (no 3rd party library)